# How to wait for an xhr request in an angular test

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I have a component with a button. When the button is clicked, an HTTP request is made:

```
this.tokensService.create(this.userInCreation).subscribe(nextCb, errorCb);
```

How do I wait for this request to be completed? Using the `async` utility and `fixture.whenStable` does not help me.

For example:

```
it('', async( async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    appPage.loginButtonEl.click(); // XHR request is initiated here
    fixture.detectChanges();

    await fixture.whenStable();

    // HTTP request is still pending here
}))
```

Comment: I think your example code should be `it('', async(async () => { ... }))`. The first `async` is the `async` utility and the second one is the keyword for making the lambda function asynchronous. Otherwise writing `await` will cause a compilation error.

Comment: Right, my bad, I forgot to add it in the example, but this isn't my problem. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: Since you are using Jasmine, I assume you are doing unit testing, therefore you won't want to make a back-end call - you would want to mock that instead.  I would do something like `spyOn(tokenService, 'create').and.returnValue(of(/*return value*/))` so that it immediately emits and completes, allowing you to test quickly.

Comment: @dmcgrandle I do wish to make back end calls in my integration tests.

Comment: Ok then, can you include the code for `TokenService`, the component you are calling it from and the rest of your spec file please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap your test with `fakeAsync` and add `tick()` inside your test.

```
it('', fakeAsync( async () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();

  appPage.loginButtonEl.click(); // XHR request is initiated here

  tick();

  fixture.detectChanges();

  await fixture.whenStable();

  // HTTP request is still pending here
}))
```

Reference:
https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick
https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My bad, I misunderstood something. But I still think you can solve it with a spy on the component where the click is happening and then just subscribing yourself in the test to the service function, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/testing-yxwsnf?file=app/dummy/dummy.component.spec.ts).

For your test this would mean the following:

```
it('', (done) => {
  fixture.detectChanges();    

  // set up spy for the function that gets called in your click() function
  // and basically replacing it with your own implementation here so you can
  // subscribe to it and wait for completion
  let spy = spyOn(appPage, 'myFunction').and.callFake(() => {
  tokensService.create(appPage.userInCreation)
    .subscribe(data => {
      fixture.detectChanges();

      // more expect statements or whatever you need here

      done();
    });
  });

  appPage.loginButtonEl.click();
});
```

Comment: This would indeed be a solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fakeAsync` instead of `async()`. I created a component, an HTTP_INTERCEPTOR to return the response after 1000ms. Here's the code

### noop-interceptor.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

/** Pass untouched request through to the next request handler. */
@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      let response = new HttpResponse();
      response = response.clone({body: 'body'});
    return of(response).pipe(delay(1000));
  }
}
```

### app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  data;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}


  getData(){
    this.http.post('asd',{}).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.data = data;
    });
  }
}
```

### app.component.html

```html
<input type='button' (click)='getData()' value='Get Data' />

<div class='response'>{{data}}</div>
```

### app.component.spec.ts

```js
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture, tick, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NoopInterceptor } from './noop-interceptor';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: NoopInterceptor, multi: true }],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
  it('should return response',fakeAsync(()=>{
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.getData();
    tick(1000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.data).toBe('body');
  
  }));
  
  it('should display response',fakeAsync(()=>{
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.getData();
    tick(1000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.response')).nativeElement;
    
    expect(element.textContent).toBe('body');
  
  }));
  
});
```

Notice the `tick(1000)`, this will advance the virtual clock

> https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-tick-function

You need to `import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';`. If the project was created using the angular-cli, it would already be there in test.ts

Read the guide here to know more about testing asyc services:

https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service

Comment: But you're not making any back-end calls are you? I wish to make real HTTP requests.

Comment: The interceptor here is mocking the http call. You can replace it with real service, give an appropriate time in tick long enough that the service returns the data